# How to switch the condition with changing the output?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I modify the condition to (parent.right != None or parent.right != n) and switch the output, it gives different result. What I want is when the condition above is fulfill, the return will be None.

```
if (parent.right == None or parent.right == n):
    return parent
else:
    return None
```

Comment: `(parent.right != None or parent.right != n)` will always be true. You need `and` instead of `or`

Comment: what about switching the return statements? or return None if the first condition is fulfilles (but then you will return None on both cases).

Comment: kuro, it works fine. thank you

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you just want to change the condition **and** the result. Making it do the same thing. You just need to change the inside of `if` and `else`

```
if (parent.right != None or parent.right != n):
    return None
else:
    return parent
```

Comment: so if (parent.right != None and parent.right != p)?

Comment: @KMP So the thing is, here you use `or` between two conditions which indicates that, if either one of them is true, the code below will run. When you change the statement to `parent.right != None or parent.right != n` it says that, when parent.right is not equal to `None` or it is not equal to `n` run the code below.